# Reading CSV in R creates new columns with X

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I read a csv in R and ran into a problem where it creates a bunch of columns after the data as shown in the picture. [image: Dataframe]

How could I remove these columns as there seems to be over 100 of them

This is the code I tried

```
df = read.csv('episodesReview.csv', head = T)
```

EDIT:
This is the code which got it to work

```
df = read.csv('episodesReview.csv', head = T, )
df = df[, c("Episode.Name", "Show.Name", "Episode.Review")]
```

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag home page regarding how to ask questions. In particular the question should include a complete reproducible example so that others can copy and paste from the question into their R session and see the same result you see.  The code and input are both missing currently; however, if you are using `read.csv` then note the `check.names=` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to select the first three columns after reading the file:

```
df = df[,c(1:3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally this should be solved while reading the data but we don't exactly know why those empty columns are coming.

So we can keep the columns which have at least 1 value which is not empty.

```
df <- df[colSums(df != '') > 0]
```

Or with `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% select(where(~any(. != '')))
```

Comment: I've tried these and that did not work, are they any other solutions?